# Angular New Router remove /# from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-new-router

I'm on angular 1.4.6 and new router version 0.5.3 and wanted to remove the '/#' from the url. Can't seem to find anything about it on the Internet.

Edit: `$locationProvider.html5mode(true);`
gives the following error:
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
TypeError: $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function`

Comment: Check this article out
https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove Hashtag from URLs only in browsers that support HTML5 History API. As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=Session%20history%20management), it's not supported in IE9, so in that case it will fallback to Hashtags.

Having said that, to make your URLs pretty in browsers that do support, you can enable `html5Mode` using `$locationProvider` config like below.

```
  angular.module('myApp', [])  
         .config(function($locationProvider){
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
         });
```

In addition to this, you need to define the base URL of your application for the angular-router to identify the routes. If your URL is

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/#showLogin` 
`http://localhost:8080/myApp/#showHomePage`

then you need to define the base URL using `<base>` tag like below

```
<head>
    <base href="/myApp">
</head>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: forgot to add, that, that doesn't work! I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
TypeError: $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function`

Comment: It's `html5Mode` with a capital `M` not `html5mode` :)

Comment: you can remove the need of base by passing the option 
`{
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
}`
to $locationProvider
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```