# Getting issue while routing the path using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have one little bit issue while routing the path using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> app.js:

```
var GoFastoApp=angular.module('GofastoHome',['ngRoute']);
GoFastoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'view/home.html',
        controller  : 'homecontroller'
    })
    .when('/deptinfo',{
        templateUrl : 'view/info.html',
        controller  : 'infocontroller'
    })
    .when('/TimeTable',{
        templateUrl : 'view/time.html',
        controller  : 'timecontroller'
    })
    .when('/course',{
        templateUrl : 'view/course.html',
        controller  : 'coursecontroller'
    })
    .when('/subject',{
        templateUrl : 'view/subject.html',
        controller  : 'subjectcontroller'
    })
    .when('/hod',{
        templateUrl : 'view/hod.html',
        controller  : 'hodcontroller'
    })
    .when('/faculty',{
        templateUrl : 'view/faculty.html',
        controller  : 'facultycontroller'
    })
})
```

When i am typing the url `oditek.in/Gofast/` on the address bar of browser the required page is coming but after getting the page the the address bar url is showing `oditek.in/Gofast/#/` .Here i am getting the unwanted `#` with this url and need to remove this.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you turn on html5 mode?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757368/angular-new-router-remove-from-url/32758015#32758015)

Comment: Did you enable html5Mode and define `<base>` as explained in that answer ? Are you still facing the issue ? What is the browser that you're testing this ?

Comment: @Arkantos : i am testing in google chrome. Can I write `$routeProvider.html5Mode(true);` in this file ?

Comment: @Arkantos : i did as per that answer but it is throwing some error.

Comment: Nope. `html5Mode` method is on $locationProvider only. What is the error that you see in your console ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91094/discussion-between-satya-and-arkantos).

Comment: This is how angularjs routing works by default. Be aware when you set html5 mode on you will remove this, you might want to edit your .htaccess, web.config, ... file to always point to your index.html
Also, in browsers that don't support the html5 mode, it will fall back to using the # again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `html5Mode` and also specify the `<base>` URL value in your markup like below.

**app.js**

```
GoFastoApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });

   // remaining router config goes here
});
```

Usually it's preferred to have `<base>` inside your `<head>`, but if you have CSS & JS files outside of `<head>`, then add it at the bottom of your HTML page, probably after all CSS and JS files, before closing the `<body>`, define the baseURI like below.

```
<base href="/Gofast/">
```